# Using the combination Future results in a list ,create a pie chart

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Use this this to draw pie chart using charts_flutter package.

ticketStatusList is the combination of 4 results coming from 4 APIs....

```
  List<charts.Series<Graph, int>> dataList(List<Count> 
     ticketStatusList) {
       List<Graph> list =  List();
        /*list.add(Graph(ticketStatusList[0]));
         list.add(Graph(ticketStatusList[1]));
       list.add(Graph(ticketStatusList[2]));
      list.add(Graph(ticketStatusList[3]));*/ error

return [
   charts.Series<Graph, int>(
    id: 'Sales',
    domainFn: (Graph sales, _) => sales.total,
    measureFn: (Graph sales, _) => sales.total,
    data: list,
    labelAccessorFn: (Graph row, _) => '${row.total}',
  )
];
      }
}

  class Graph {
   int total;

     Graph(this.total);
}
```

A pie  chart  using this list

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the model class for graph and use the same list to draw it.